# in j2me lwuit,with theme the combobox drop down and other component will hide

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

without theme combobox drop down correctly and other component show correctly. when using theme combobox drop down but other component will hide.

```
    Form f;
    TextField t4;
    ComboBox com1, com2, com3;
    Container c1, c2, c3, c4;
    Button add;
    Command back, save;
    Resources resources;

    public void startApp() {
        Display.init(this);
        try {
            resources = Resources.open("/nn.res");
            UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(resources.getTheme(resources.getThemeResourceNames()[0]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        f = new Form("Form");
        f.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        com1 = new ComboBox(new String[]{"123", "234", "345", "456"});
        com2 = new ComboBox(new String[]{"123", "234", "345", "456"});
        com3 = new ComboBox(new String[]{"123", "234", "345", "456"});

        t4 = new TextField(5);
        back = new Command("Back", 1);
        save = new Command("Save", 2);

        add = new Button("kjkk");

        c1 = new Container(new FlowLayout());
        c2 = new Container(new FlowLayout());
        c3 = new Container(new FlowLayout());
        c4 = new Container(new BorderLayout());



        c1.addComponent(new Label("Project Name:"));
        c1.addComponent(com3);

        c2.addComponent(new Label("Description:"));
        c2.addComponent(com1);

        c3.addComponent(new Label("Sub Category:"));
        c3.addComponent(com2);

        c4.addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST, new Label("Qty:"));
        c4.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, t4);
        c4.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST, add);

        f.addComponent(c1);
        f.addComponent(c2);
        f.addComponent(c3);
        f.addComponent(c4);

        f.addCommand(back);
        f.addCommand(save);

        f.show();


    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its never happen when you are using with or without Resource Edit file. Just add the Selected and Unselected style for components. Look at this article for [building themes using Resource Edit.](http://www.themeswiki.org/Building_themes_using_LWUIT) Also Lot of video's available for [building a theme with new Resource Edit.](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2010/11/new-resource-editor-tutorial-part-1.html)